# Python Outlier Detection in Customer Sales (preferbly by pyod)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big Sales transaction dataset that has multiple customers and each customer buys multiple products. I am struggling to find outliers for each customer and all products at the same time.

Please help. My dataset sample is as below. I am fine with basic methods.
I have one master dataset and I like to see multiple the result via multiple datasets. Thank you.

Sample Dataset:

```
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Customer": [
                "A0",
                "A0",
                "A0",
                "A0",
                "A1",
                "A1",
                "A1",
                "A1",
                "A2",
                "A2",
                "A2",
                "A2",
            ],
            "Date": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4,],
            "Eggs": [1, 1, 2, 10, 3, 3, 4, 10, 10, 11, 12, 22],
            "Bread": [66, 10, 20, 11, 3, 3, 4, 10, 44, 11, 12, 22],
        },
    )
```

Result Dataset 1:

```
result1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Customer": ["A0", "A1", "A2",], "Date": [4, 4, 4,], "Eggs": [10, 10, 22],},
)
```

Result Dataset 2:

```
result2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Customer": ["A0", "A1", "A2",], "Date": [1, 4, 1,], "Bread": [66, 10, 44],},
)
```